# How do I Trim All incoming Json object fields in MVC WEB API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

what I'm trying to achieve is to trim all incoming object properties of type string in MVC Web Api project.

I thought that model binder should be a solution, but it's not being hit, if I try to set a custom model binder instead of `ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder`..

the Json for example is `{"Name": "      Test Name      ", "Number": 15}`

For example - If I specify `ModelBinder` explicitly, it works..

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomBinder))]
    public class TestObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
    }
```

The Controller ...

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // POST api/test
   public void Post([ModelBinder(typeof(MyCustomBinder))]TestObject value)
   {
   }
```

And the Registration

```
 ModelBinders.Binders.Add(new KeyValuePair<Type, IModelBinder>(typeof(TestObject), new MyCustomBinder()));
```

But I want to **find a more generalized** approach, so I wouldn't need to decorate each and every model class in my project

Comment: Can you show us what is the json you are trying to receive and your expected result, and some code on what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if **your** client-side code sends something like `" Test Name "` with whitespaces, than the user might actually want it to be that way. However, if you attending to prevent him doing so, in a hard way, not in handling the `<input type='text' .. />` on the frontend, you might end up accessing the `Form` collection of a request.

```
public ViewResult Index()
{
    Request.Form["Name"] = Request.Form["Name"].Trim();

    return View();
}
```

Or, you could do it in some several other ways:

- You could make a common asbtract controller class, which will do the same thing in its `OnActionExecuting` method.
- You could define an `ActionFilter` attribute class, which will do it whatever method or controller class you mark with it.

Since you are working in a limited edition of a controller, you can still access the `Request` property just so:

```
HttpRequestBase request = ((HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request;
```

Comment: The thing is - I'm working on WEB API, I do have no forms.. And I want to prevent users from creating "Accounts" or "Users" with spaces in front or the end..